# Code can't compile because "actual and formal argument lists differ from in length

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, arguments, variadic-functions

Here is my code:

```
public class RSubuntuPgm1 { 
    public static void main (String arg[]){
        
        System.out.printf("\ngedit");
        System.out.printf("\nCtrl + S");
        System.out.printf("\nAlt + F4");
        processUbuntu();
    }
    public void processUbuntu(String name, String date, double number){

        name = "Sean";
        number = 2021.99;
        date = "Fall";
        System.out.printf("\n%s",name);
        System.out.printf("\n%.5f",number); // 10 spaces, 5 more spaces for decimals
        System.out.printf("\n%S",date); //capital S makes all capital
    }
}
```

It has to be formatted this way because it's graded work. The error is because I'm trying to call the void method.

Comment: You're not passing `processUbuntu` any parameters when you call it. Your method definition is asking for 3.

Comment: As an aside, why have you declared parameters for the method if you're then not going to use the values that were passed in? Perhaps you need to revisit the purpose of method parameters?

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code.

- You need to pass values to a function that has parameters (this is the error mentioned in the title)
- You can't call an instance method directly from a static method without a reference to an instance

And there are some additional tips:

- Don't reassign values in the `processUbuntu` function

The right code should be

```
public class RSubuntuPgm1 { 
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        System.out.printf("\ngedit");
        System.out.printf("\nCtrl + S");
        System.out.printf("\nAlt + F4");
       
        // You need to pass the values for the parameters name, date, number
        processUbuntu("Sean", "Fall", 2021.99);
    }

    // Added the static keyword
    public static void processUbuntu(String name, String date, double number) {
        // You don't need to reassign the values so the following lines are commented
        // name = "Sean"; 
        // number = 2021.99;
        // date = "Fall";
        System.out.printf("\n%s",name);
        System.out.printf("\n%.5f",number); // 10 spaces, 5 more spaces for decimals
        System.out.printf("\n%S",date); //capital S makes all capital
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one problem but not the one causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `processUbuntu();`
but the method signature is: `processUbuntu(String name, String date, double number)`
meaning it requires two strings and a double to be passed in.

Try: `processUbuntu("Sean", "Fall", 2021.99);` and get rid of the assignments in the method body.

The actual error in the question is telling you "processUbuntu requires 3 arguments, but you're providing zero" in a more general way.

Then see David Lorenzo MARINO's answer for the next bug.